# ComboBox event that runs after BindingSource has updated

Tags: vb.net, events, combobox

I am using a ComboBox tied to a BindingSource.

After selecting the appropriate choice, I need a bunch of things to happen, but the BindingSource needs to be up to date first, in other words the current record needs to be fully loaded before continuing.

I am currently using the DropDownClosed event, but other TextBoxes bound to the same binding source haven't updated yet. Is there another event I can use?

Comment: There is a `DataSourceChanged` event

Comment: You should be handling the `CurrentChanged` event of the `BindingSoure`.